# How to align region borders?

Tags: interface

Back in the old days, it was fairly easy to merge windows. They moved in regular steps of x pixels and they always lined up.

For quite some time now I sometimes experience situations like this:

[image]

Since they don't line up and the movement seems too coarse, it's impossible to merge the horizontal regions. What to do?

Answer (score 2):

And just as I was typing a few days ago, I thought to try out ctrl and yes, ctrl does the trick. Just hold <kbd>LMB</kbd> on a border and then add <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

Comment: I was hesitant to answer or to ask (took me 3 days to work up the courage), but it seems nobody has asked this one, unless I haven't found it. It's not about the usual T-corner problem. I hope it helps somebody in the future.